# ActionBar Sherlock not being added as library, eclipse?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to add the Action Bar Sherlock with my application. Adding it as library. Wherein it gives the following error.

```
    Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
    but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
    All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
    Versions found are:
    Path: E:\VFCApps\SARGroup\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 648327
SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
    Path: E:\VFCApps\appcompat_v7_2\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 648327
SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
    Path: E:\VFCApps\actionbarsherlock\libs\android-support-v4.jar
Length: 271754
SHA-1: 53307dc2bd2b69fd5533458ee11885f55807de4b
    Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
    E:\VFCApps\appcompat_v7_2\res\values\attrs.xml:32: error: Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
    E:\VFCApps\appcompat_v7_2\res\values\attrs.xml:33: error: Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
```

and so on...

The R.java is deleted automatically from my main project on adding library.

Comment: `android-support-v4.jar` libs are different. Use one of them, just copy from one project and replace in other. And why are you trying to add `actionbarsherlock` and `appcompat_v7_2` together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the `android-support-v4.jar` from your project and paste it in the `libs` folder in  `appcompat_v7_2` and `actionbarsherlock` and then clean and build them all.

Answer (score 0):

Replace android-support-v4.jar of Sherlock Action Bar Library project
with the jar of your project and clean and build the project

Answer (score 0):

As the first line itself says you have 3 android-support-v4.jar files in your project.

1. libs - in you project
2. libs - appcompat library
3. libs - in sherlock library

My question to you is, why you need sherlock library when you have the appcompat library.

just remove the sherlock library, remove the android-support-v4.jar from libs in your project, clean and run the project. Have the android-support-v4.jar only in you appcompat library.